# C# Sorted list: How to get the next element?

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I'm wondering how to get the next element in a C# sorted list. SO far I've come up with the following code:

```
SortedList<int, Bla> mList;

Bla someElement = mList[key];
Bla next        = mList[mList.Keys[mList.IndexOfKey(key) + 1]];
```

I'm not sure if that's the smartest way to do it ;-)

Comment: Oops, sorry. I've added the declaration of the list...

Comment: Can't you just keep a separate index variable?

Comment: foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Bla> entry in mList){ ... } ????

Comment: Use IndexOfKey and GetByIndex.

Comment: @HansPassant If you post that as an answer I'll upvote it.  Everyone else here seems incapable of answering the question that was actually asked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you can access a `SortedList` by [index (see the Remarks section)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx), I'd recommend using the following:

```
var index = mList.IndexOfKey(key);
var first = mList.Values[index];
var second = mList.Values[index + 1];
```

This will work in the same `O(log n)` as a single lookup.

Here's also the LINQ way to do it:

```
var items = mList.SkipWhile(m => m.Key != key).Select(m => m.Value).Take(2).ToList(); // Avoid double-enumeration by calling ToList
var first = mList[0];
var second = mList[1];
```

This will only enumerate once.  It will execute in `O(n)`.

Comment: That actually did the job. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 6):

**SortedList** can be accessed by both key and index

```
var IndexOfKey = mList.IndexOfKey(key);
```

Increment the index,

```
IndexOfKey++; //Handle last index case
```

Get the next item by index.

```
var nextElement = mList.GetByIndex(IndexOfKey);
```

Comment: Does this relate to `SortedList<int, Bla>` ? SortedList under Generics doesn't hv `GetByIndex` unless i misinterpreted something

Comment: @Boris... I thought you were using [SortList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx)

Comment: I hope the up-votes are not since HansPassant suggested this in the comments

Comment: @V4Vendetta Power of suggestion :)  It's a good answer though, if `GetByIndex` existed.  In reality, you must use `mList.Values[index]`.

Comment: @ScottRippey It does in the SortList in found on MSDN

Comment: @parapurarajkumar I apologize, you are correct.  The OP didn't originally specify the `SortedList`, so this is definitely a good answer.

Comment: @ScottRippey you must be kidding, `SortedList<int, Bla>`  isn't same as key/value pair of SortedList which considers `Object`

Comment: @V4Vendetta The original post did not say `SortedList<int, Bla>` ... that info was added later.

Answer (score 3):

Use enumerator:

```
 IDictionaryEnumerator iterator = mList.GetEnumerator();
 iterator.MoveNext();
 Bla first = iterator.Value;
 iterator.MoveNext();
 Bla next = iterator.Value;
```

Comment: But the OP i thought already had an element for which he wanted to find next

Comment: That's true. I'd like to find an element in the list (preferably very fast) and then iterate from there...

Comment: This gets the first 2 items, and doesn't even bother looking at the `key`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SortedList<int, Bla> mList;
int key = 0;
Bla someElement = mList.Values[key];

...
key = 1;
Bla next        = mList.Values[key];
```